The trigger doesn't stop the enemy from walking
I'm having an issue with my light system in my game made with unity, where I'm trying to stop the enemy when he touches the light emitted by the player, but when he touches the light, the enterTrigger and exitTrigger functions are called many times simultaneously. I think that maybe it's caused by the way I'm handling the light in the update method.
Player script
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
 #region Light
 [Header("Light Settings")]
 private bool lightOn;
 public GameObject lightUp;
 public GameObject lightDown;
 public GameObject lightLeft;
 public GameObject lightRight;
 #endregion

 void Start()
 {
     rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
 }

 void Update()
 {
     batterySystem.UpdateBatteryUI();
     if (canMove)
     {
         HandleMovement();
         HandleLantern();
         batterySystem.HandleBatteryUsage(lightOn);
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
         {
             batterySystem.HandleBatteryRecharge();
         }
         if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Q))
         {
             batterySystem.CancelRecharge();
         }
     }
 }
 #region Light Methods
 public void HandleLantern()
 {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && batterySystem.batteryCount > 0)
     {
         lightOn = !lightOn;

         anim.SetBool("Light", lightOn);

         if (lightOn)
         {
             UpdateLightDirection(lastMove);
         }
         else
         {
            
             DisableAllLights();
         }
     }
 }

 private void UpdateLightDirection(Vector2 direction)
 {
     DisableAllLights();

     if (Mathf.Abs(direction.x) > Mathf.Abs(direction.y))
     {
         if (direction.x > 0)
         {
             lightRight.SetActive(true);
         }
         else if (direction.x < 0)
         {
             lightLeft.SetActive(true);
         }
     }
     else
     {
         if (direction.y > 0)
         {
             lightUp.SetActive(true);
         }
         else if (direction.y < 0)
         {
             lightDown.SetActive(true);
         }
     }
 }

 private void DisableAllLights()
 {
     lightUp.SetActive(false);
     lightDown.SetActive(false);
     lightLeft.SetActive(false);
     lightRight.SetActive(false);
 }


 public void TurnOffLight()
 {
     lightOn = false;
     anim.SetBool("Light", false);
     DisableAllLights(); 
 }
 #endregion

}


Enemy Script
public class FollowEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float defaultSpeed; 
    private float distance;
    public float minimumDistance;
    public float attackDistance;

    public bool canMove = true;

    void Start()
    {
        defaultSpeed = speed; 
    }

    void Update()
    {
            Walk();               
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Light"))
        {
            canMove = false;
            speed = 0f;
            Debug.Log("Entered Light Trigger");
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Light"))
        {
            canMove = true;
            speed = defaultSpeed;
            Debug.Log("Exited Light Trigger");
        }
    }

    private void Walk()
    {
        if (canMove)
        { 
            distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position);

            Vector2 direction = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position - transform.position;
            direction.Normalize();
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

            if (distance < minimumDistance)
            {
                transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(this.transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * angle);
            }
            if (distance < attackDistance)
            {
                speed = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried to disable the the triggers too, but it didn't work, the EnterTrigger2D and the ExitTrigger2d keep being called many times.

If the lights collider is inside of the trigger when you disable the light gameobject, OnTriggerExit will be called.
This is because the collider is no longer inside of the trigger collider.
When exit gets called you allow the enemy to move again.
You would need to change how this interaction works in your game to fix the issue.
One way would be to toggle the light component instead of the entire object.  This would require a check to see if the light is on or off when implementing the other logic.

the trigger is inside the light gameobject, cause when the light is on the trigger should be on too, but for some reason when i turn the light on with the input key and the enemy collides with the trigger, somehow the OnTriggerEnter and the OnTriggerExit are being called at the same time, causing the enemy to keep moving toward the player

This is most likely caused by two issues:
Using Update instead of FixedUpdate
In Unity, the physics system does not run every frame. Rather, it runs at a fixed timestep. Because of this, Unity gives you another Update method that is tied to the physics system: FixedUpdate. FixedUpdate is to be used whenever your code relies on or modifies the physics system, otherwise, your physics becomes dependent on your framerate.
Change your Update to FixedUpdate inside of FollowEnemy, as your Walk() method moves your enemy (which is physics related, because of the OnTrigger callbacks).
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Walk();
}

Modifying the rigidbody's transform directly
Walk() does another thing that will mess with the physics system: modify its transform directly. While it'll appear to work, the enemy will jitter against walls as it temporarily moves inside them before being ejected, and the trigger callbacks might behave strangely.
To fix this, keep a reference to the enemy's Rigidbody2D and change the velocity, rather than the transform.position:
public class FollowEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Add and assign within Unity's Inspector:
    public Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    // The rest of your variables here...

    // Your other functions here...
 
    private void Walk()
    {
        if (canMove)
        { 
            distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position);

            Vector2 direction = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position - transform.position;
            direction.Normalize();
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

            if (distance < minimumDistance)
            {
                rigidbody.velocity = direction * speed;
                rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * angle);
            }
            else
            {
                rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            }
            if (distance < attackDistance)
            {
                speed = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}


thanks for the answer, but it doesn't solve my problem, the enemy keeps moving towards the player even if the lantern is on, in the console the functions OnTriggerEnter2D and OnTriggerExit2D, are being called many times and the same time when the enemy enter the light trigger, when i turn the light direct from the inspector the trigger works and the enemy stops, but when i try turning it on with the input key, the enemy doesn't stop.
